# SQL excluding rows using INNER JOINs throws error: expected 'UDFCALLNAME' (Teradata)

Tags: sql, syntax-error, inner-join, teradata

#### Join Tables

I have a query where I **inner join**:

1. *first table* (A)
2. *second table* (B)
3. *third table* (C)

#### Exclude IDs

I would like to **exclude rows** *which meet some conditions* of (C) from result joining (A) with (B).

I have the query as below but I am not getting the desired results.

Any help with excluding **ID**s in (C) from (A x B) would be greatly appreciated. I want to exclude **ID**s who are on those *meds*.

#### Error

I am also getting an error:

```
expected 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword between ')' and ')'
```

#### SQL on Teradata

```
 select distinct first_visit.pat_id, 
            first_visit.PatientMRN, 
            first_visit.PatientName, 
            cast(contact_date as  date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') as visit_date, 
            first_visit.hsp_account_id as hsp_acct
from            
(
SELECT  distinct pat.pat_id,
    pat.PAT_MRN_ID as PatientMRN,
    pat.PAT_NAME as PatientName,
    contact_date,
    cast(pat.Birth_Date as  date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') as DOB,
    cast(contact_date as date) - cast( pat.birth_date as date) year (4) AS PatAge,
   enc.enc_type_c,
   dept.specialty,
   dept.department_name,
    specName.NAME,
    prov_name,
    acct.hsp_account_id     
FROM  Patient pat
inner JOIN  HSP_ACCOUNT acct on  acct.PAT_ID = pat.PAT_ID 
inner JOIN  Pat_enc enc on  enc.PAT_ID = pat.PAT_ID 
inner join clarity_ser_dept ser  on ser.prov_id = enc.visit_prov_id
inner join clarity_ser prov on prov.prov_id = ser.prov_id 
inner join CLARITY_SER_SPEC spec on enc.visit_prov_id = spec.PROV_ID 
inner join ZC_SPECIALTY specName on specName.SPECIALTY_C = spec.SPECIALTY_C and spec.LINE=1 and specName.NAME = 'xxx'
inner join CLARITY_DEP Dept on Dept.DEPARTMENT_ID = enc.DEPARTMENT_ID  and dept.specialty = specname.name
inner join CLARITY_LOC provLoc on provLoc.LOC_ID = Dept.REV_LOC_ID
where patAge > 55
and cast(contact_date as  date format 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= '10/01/2018'
and ACCT_CLASS_HA_C  =  '1207'
and acct.CODING_STATUS_C = 4 
and acct.ACCT_BILLSTS_HA_C NOT IN (40, 60, 99) 
AND SUBSTR(CAST (acct.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR(18)),4,1) IN ('1','3')
and enc_type_c  = '101'
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
qualify row_number() over (partition by PatientMRN  order by contact_date DESC) =1) first_visit


inner join 
(select problem.pat_ID, edg.DX_ID, noted_date
from problem_list problem
inner join clarity_edg edg on problem.DX_ID = edg.DX_ID  
--where pat_id = '212000001293964'
and DX_name like any ('%Atrial FLutter%', '%Atrial Fib%')
) DX on DX.pat_id = first_visit.pat_id and DX.noted_date < first_visit.contact_date

/* exclude */
left  join 
(select distinct pat_id 
from (select pat_id from order_med ordmed
inner join RX_MED_TWO rxmed  on ordmed.medication_id = rxmed.medication_id 
inner join ZC_ADMIN_ROUTE  zc on ADMIN_ROUTE_C = zc.med_route_c 
where medication_name  like any ( '%Coumadin%',  '%Eliquis%'))) meds
on first_visit.pat_id = meds.pat_id 
where meds.pat_id is null;
```

Thank you!
JH

Comment: How would we know what you want?  You haven't explained your logic, much less provided sample data and desired results.

Comment: Use a where clause to exclude rows

Comment: At first blush, your SQL looks overly complicated. Why do you have all the internal `select * from` expressions?

Comment: What technology are you using?  Also you never want to select *, bad practice.  This is extemely over complicated

Comment: I think that you truely need to understand inner joins at a base level, there should be no reason to have any of these inner selects going on. Take a look at this article and see if this helps you any. http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-inner-join/ 

Basically when you use an INNER JOIN you will have an ON statement that will link the table being joined to the tables already in the dataset. Then, if needed, you can have additional where conditions below that.

Comment: I have selected fields in the actual code.

Comment: @dmoore1181 I think using an inner join in the `FROM` clause is preferred over listing your tables and using a WHERE clause to reduce your results for the effect of an inner join.

Comment: Hey @JHegde. Please [edit] your question and __tell us more conretly__ (1) what tables contain which columns (the __schema__), (2) for __which purpose__ like to combine/_INNER JOIN_ them, and (3) what __result you expected__ ? We would like not only to correct your SQL but __to find the best solution__.

Comment: @hc_dev please find the complete query below . I edited my original question and posted the complete query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a bunch of problems with you sample SQL.

Using `(Select * from A)Table_A` in a `FROM` clause is unnecessary, as it is the same as `A Table_A`.  This simplifies your sample to the following:

```
select distinct Table_ABC.id, 
                 Table_ABC.name,
         Table_ABC.Age 
 from
(
  A Table_A

  inner join (B Table_B on Table_A.id = Table_B.id) Table_AB

  inner join (C Table_C on Table_C.id <> TableAB.id and (condition)
)Table_ABC
```

Next, if tables `A`, `B`, and `C` have a field named `id`, then `Table_ABC.id` is still going to be ambiguous.  Instead, specify the table you want to use for the `id` field.
I'd also get rid of the `Table_AB` and `Table_ABC` aliases.
I also question the aliases `Table_A`, `Table_B`, and `Table_C`.
Typically one sees aliases to make the table names *shorter* (when not aliasing to avoid ambiguity) but here you make them *longer*.

```
select distinct Table_A.id, Table_A.name, Table_A.Age 
from A Table_A
  inner join B Table_B on Table_A.id = Table_B.id
  inner join C Table_C on Table_C.id <> Table_A.id and (condition)
```

Now, finally, to exclude when the join matches on C, do an outer join and use a where clause for the NULL values created by the outer join.

```
select distinct Table_A.id, Table_A.name, Table_A.Age 
from A Table_A
  inner join B Table_B on Table_A.id = Table_B.id
  left outer join C Table_C on Table_C.id = Table_A.id and (condition)
where Table_C.id is NULL
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Marlin Pierce